# RxJava2 lift vs compose (ObservableOperator vs ObservableTransformer)

Tags: java, rx-java2

When I need to implement custom compound transformations on `Observable` I'm used to implement `ObservableTransformer` and then chain it using `compose` method. But recently, I've discovered that there is also `lift` method, which receives `ObservableOperator` and it feels that it provides rather similar functionality.

At first glance, `compose` and `ObservableTransformer` looks to me simpler and more flexible, than `lift` with `ObservableOperator`, but may be it's just due to the lack of my experience with `lift`.

So the question is, what are **pros** of **cons** of using `compose` vs `lift`? In which situations it's better to use `lift` than `compose` and vice versa. Are there any performance penalty considerations when using each one of them?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0#creating-operator-classes

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks, I've already read this and I understand how to use `lift`. But I still could not find any information about comparison with `compose`. In my opinion, with `compose` it's possible to do the same things, but in syntactically simpler manner, so I'm trying to understand whether there are reasons to use `lift` instead of `compose`

Comment: Whichever feels more comfortable to you. I use `compose` in my support libraries because of less indirection and more subscription control.